# Referencing JQuery function in external .js file - syntax?

Tags: jquery

I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious, but I'm new to all of this, so please forgive a cry for help!

How exactly should I call a jQuery function of my own stored in a separate .js file? I've developed a working prototype of my app but am now trying to tidy up the code, and move various jQuery functions into a separate file where I can access them on each page. But for some reason I'm finding it impossible to access the code once I've turned it into a named function, either in the head of my html document or in the separate .js file. Crucially, I can't find a simple reference to the correct syntax for actually calling the function!

Anyway, here's the relevant bits of code:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobilecus-1.1.0.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myjquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">

<div data-role="page" id="page1" class="page">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("alert1!");
        $(InitRightBar());   /// This is the problem!
        });
        </script>
...
</div>
...
</body>
```

And the entirety of the separate "myjquery.js" file:

```
$(function() { //ready

function InitRightBar (){
alert("alert2!");
$("#rightbar").live("swipeleft", function(){
                  $.mobile.changePage($("#page2"))
            });
}

}); //end ready
```

NB: Alert 1 is always firing, but Alert 2 never fires, even if I put it the function in the html head. I've tried multiple different syntaxes instead of "$(InitRightBar());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you JS File , keep only these lines

```
   function InitRightBar (){
      alert("alert2!");
       $("#rightbar").live("swipeleft", function(){
              $.mobile.changePage($("#page2"))
        });
    }
```

and remove the First and the last line.Also change the following

```
   $(InitRightBar());   /// This is the problem!
```

to

```
   InitRightBar();
```

only.

Comment: Thanks so much for a swift answer - that seems to have fixed it! :-)